# Removing the added "\n" parts from a list created from a text file

Tags: python, list

I read lines from a text file to get list of paths, the txt file sample is:

```
/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/edg/fms/river_routes_gt74Sto61S=river_destination_field ,
/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p1/mom4p1a/mom4_ecosystem/preprocessing/rho0_profile.nc ,
/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p0/mom4p0c/mom4_test8/preprocessing/fe_dep_ginoux_gregg_om3_bc.nc=Soluble_Fe_Flux_PI.nc ,
/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/jwd/regression_data/esm2.1/input/cover_type_1860_g_ens=cover_type_field ,
```

To read it I'm using:

```
x = open('/File_list.txt', 'r')
y = [line.split(',') for line in x.readlines()]
```

But each element have now `\n` at the end, for example for `y[2]`:

```
['/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p0/mom4p0c/mom4_test8/preprocessing/fe_dep_ginoux_gregg_om3_bc.nc=Soluble_Fe_Flux_PI.nc ',
 '\n']
```

How do I remove these unecessary `\n`?
Tried:

```
good = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in y]
```

But got the error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-d3ed0e6bdc26> in <module>
----> 1 good = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in y]

<ipython-input-33-d3ed0e6bdc26> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 good = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in y]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Seems like a simple issue but I couldn't resolve it yet.
​

Comment: Assuming you file is like : 
"
path1,\n
path2,\n
path3
"
you may not have to split using ',' as each line is already an item to append to your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help. You can check if the line is empty using `if line.strip()`

**Ex:**

```
with open('/File_list.txt') as infile:
    #good = [line.strip().split(",") for line in infile if line.strip()]
    good = [line.strip(" ,\n") for line in infile if line.strip()]
```

Comment: I tried, but for some reason I still get ```' '``` at the end, I need the element ```y[2]``` to be ```'/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p0/mom4p0c/mom4_test8/preprocessing/fe_dep_ginoux_gregg_om3_bc.nc=Soluble_Fe_Flux_PI.nc'``` Is it possible?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your text ? and expected output of it

Comment: Looks like you need `good = [line.strip().strip(",").strip() for line in infile if line.strip()]` ? or `good = [line.strip(" ,\n") for line in infile if line.strip()]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `.strip` method before split, it will remove any non-printable character from the end of a line such as \r, \n, \t, etc.

```
x = open('/File_list.txt', 'r')
y = [line.strip().split(',') for line in x.readlines()]
```

If the number of lines in the file is small(say less than 1000 or 10000), you can also use `.read` method instead of `.readlines` like below:

```
x = open('/File_list.txt', 'r')
y = x.read().strip().split('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Itamar Mushkin for correcting my formatting.

Comment: You're welcome, it's common practice here and nothing to worry about :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
with open("/File_list.txt", "r") as f:
    data = [line.replace("\n","").strip(",").strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

---

**Output:**

```
['/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/edg/fms/river_routes_gt74Sto61S=river_destination_field',
 '/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p1/mom4p1a/mom4_ecosystem/preprocessing/rho0_profile.nc',
 '/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/fms/mom4/mom4p0/mom4p0c/mom4_test8/preprocessing/fe_dep_ginoux_gregg_om3_bc.nc=Soluble_Fe_Flux_PI.nc',
 '/data0/home/rslat/GFDL/archive/jwd/regression_data/esm2.1/input/cover_type_1860_g_ens=cover_type_field']
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

Reading all the file :

```
x = open('/File_list.txt', 'r')
fileData = x.read()
y = fileData.split(',')
// can use y.pop() to remove the last empty element if existing
```

Reading by lines :

```
x = open('/File_list.txt', 'r')
y = [line[:-1] for line in x.readlines()]
// just remove the last ',' on the line, don't need to split
```